# ARMv8-A architecture register PMUSERENR_EL0

Tags: arm

I am new to arm architecture.

In my testing program, there is an assembly code to read PMCR_EL0 register. (like below)

```
mrs x0, pmcr_el0
```

But when I execute the program, it occurs exception with "Illegal instruction".

I searched "ARM a53 technical reference manual", then I found following sentence.

> This register is accessible at EL0 when PMUSERENR_EL0.EN is set to 1.

and EL1 was required to write a value to PMUSERENR_EL0.EN.

So, I wrote kernel module which set PMUSERENR_EL0.EN bit to 1 when it upload by `insmod` shell command.

But after the kernel moduel upload, when I execute my testing program there is still occuring exception with "Illegal instruction". So, I checked the value of PMUSERENR_EL0 register via additional assembly code `mrs x0, PMUSERENR_EN0`, and its value is still 0.

I'm not sure what went wrong. How can I set the PMUSERENR_EL0.EN bit to 1 and finally read the PMCR_EL0 register value in user space application?

My computing environment is Raspberrypi 3 B v1.2(ARM cortex A53) and raspabian 64 bit OS.

Comment: For starters, the RPi 3B has four cores, and you've only set the flag on one of them, which will not necessarily be the one that runs your process.  Normally the way you control hardware features on a multitasking system is to have the kernel save and restore the state on every context switch, so that each process gets its own view.  It may be that the kernel already does this, which would also defeat your module's attempt to set it.

Comment: Normally you would access the performance counters via the [Perf subsystem](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) instead of directly reading the registers.  Have you checked whether that could get you the data you want?